# Как сгенерировать digest пароль на dart

Tags: dart, onvif

Для подключения к ip камере нужно пройти верификацию
Формула вроде как такая должна быть [источник на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443835/whats-the-formula-of-onvif-passworddigest)
. [Первоисточник стандарта шифрования](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm#xml-schema1)

```
Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )
```

Я делаю вот так, но пароль не подходит

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
var mNonce = base64Encode(utf8.encode("12345678901234567890"));
Digest digest = sha1.convert(utf8.encode(mNonce + '2019-12-25T07:55:35Z' + '12345'));
var mPasswordDigest = base64Encode(digest.bytes);
```

Это тело корректного http запроса, который работает

```html
'<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '
      'xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">'
      '<v:Header><Action mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/GetSnapshotUri</Action>'
      '<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">'
      '<UsernameToken><Username>admin</Username>'
      '<Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'
      '8mdx0yoK22pKuN2NggG945oJZdA=</Password>'
      '<Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'
      'MTYyYTRmMzExYjBhMDE3Nw==</Nonce>'
      '<Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">'
      '2019-12-23T14:11:08Z</Created></UsernameToken></Security></v:Header>'
      '<v:Body><GetSnapshotUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">'
      '<ProfileToken>PROFILE_000</ProfileToken></GetSnapshotUri></v:Body></v:Envelope>';
```

т.е  должны быть примерно такие значения

```
    var onvifCreated = '2019-12-25T07:55:35Z';
    var onvifNonce = 'Njg2YzYxZDI4YjA4ZDA0Nw==';
    var onvifPass = 'x8IytKlr8cTH+sT9EzEaVDLqYGw=';
```

Comment: У даты правильный формат? Мб нужно указывать миллисекунды?

Comment: Нет формат даты правильный, думаю проблема вся в хэшировании, кодировках и т.д. Сомнения по поводу правильности получения sha-1, т.е. вот это:                                     
  Digest digest = sha1.convert(utf8.encode(mNonce + '2019-12-25T07:55:35Z' + '12345'));

Comment: В первой ссылке (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629145/5909792), в комменте была ссылка на gists (https://gist.github.com/lsowen/1a46f9d5fc026e6efc7d#file-onvif_request-py-L12) и там формат даты указывал миллисекунды, правда как `000`, например: `2019-12-25T10:46:24.000Z`

Comment: В рабочий запрос добавил милисекунды (000) - сломалось

Answer (score 0):

В формуле наверху ошибка. Вот так правильно:

> Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1(Nonce  + Date + Password ) )

Вот правильный код:

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
var mNonce = base64Encode(utf8.encode("12345678901234567890"));
Digest digest = sha1.convert(utf8.encode("12345678901234567890"+ '2019-12-25T07:55:35Z' + '12345'));
var mPasswordDigest = base64Encode(digest.bytes);
```